# jquery chosen limit of maximum select boxes (dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found weird limitation of jquery `chosen`: I have big generated amount of select boxes (dropdowns). I do not mean options - I mean elements marked by `<select></select>` tags).

When amount of dropdowns reaches more then 138 (maybe not exactly - I generate dropdowns in sets of 6 and last working amount is 138, 144 is not working)

In my opinion it's not so many dropdowns to be some memory or executing limitation... do anyone know some fix for this? I've tryed everything (progressively ajax loading with calling `$('#id').chosen()` after load of course etc.) but what only helps was decreasing the amount of dropdowns.

when I progressively load dropdowns, it works perfect until the 24-th six comes (139.-144. dropdowns)

thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: Could you please post some source code and go into more detail about what you mean with "it stops working"? Do you see any error message, browser crashes, .... ? Also, have you tried different browsers and a minimum (non)-working example without progressive ajax loading?

Comment: interesting issue, but agreed, need more data. any errors would definitely help.

Comment: Minimum is that 138 dropdowns, doesn't matter if you load them with or without progressive load. By stop working I mean this: options box is defaultly displayed in the mostly top right corner of the second parent positioned div.
I can't publish examples.

Comment: firebug console has no errors